# for loop run command in from file

Tags: linux, bash, for-loop, scripting

I have store commands in file and i want to capture their output, but what is wrong here?

I want to capture output of each command and store in relevant file.

Following just example, i have 100s of command which i want to run and capture optput but i just stuck in my demo testig in following code.

My foo.txt

```
/bin/ls
/bin/cat /etc/redhat-release
```

My for loop

```
[spatel@linux ~]$ IFS=$'\n'
[spatel@linux ~]$ for qw in `cat foo.txt`; do echo $qw; done
backup  bar  final.sh  foo.txt  input.txt
-bash: /bin/cat /etc/redhat-release: No such file or directory
```

Why `/bin/ls` run but `/bin/cat /etc/redhat-release` not run

**UPDATE:**

```
[spatel@linux ~]$ /bin/cat /etc/redhat-release
CentOS release 6.6 (Final)
```

Comment: Start a new bash and try again. I can not reproduce your problem. This two lines of code only print content of file foo.txt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your command as shown, neither `ls` not `cat` is actually executed:

```
$ for qw in `cat foo.txt`; do echo $qw; done
/bin/ls
/bin/cat /etc/redhat-release
```

To get the output that you show, I suspect that you actually ran this command;

```
$ for qw in `cat foo.txt`; do $qw; done
foo.txt
bash: /bin/cat /etc/redhat-release: No such file or directory
```

In this case, `ls` is executed but `/bin/cat /etc/redhat-release` is not executed because there is no command whose name is the full string `/bin/cat /etc/redhat-release`.  (The shell does not do word-splitting here.)

To see this in a simpler example:

```
$ ls *.txt
foo.txt
$ a="ls *.txt"; $a
bash: ls *.txt: command not found
```

#### Executing all the commands and capturing output to file

To execute all the command in foo.txt, run:

```
$ bash foo.txt
foo.txt
CentOS release 6.6 (Final)
```

To run all the commands and capture their output to file `output.log`, then run:

```
bash foo.txt >output.log
```

To run all the commands and show their output on screen while also capturing the output to a file:

```
$ bash foo.txt | tee output.log
foo.txt
CentOS release 6.6 (Final)
```

#### Capturing each command's output to a different file

First, run awk on `foo.txt` to create `foo.sh`:

```
$ awk '{sub(/$/, (" >output" ++count))} 1' foo.txt >foo.sh
```

This is what `foo.sh` looks like:

```
$ cat foo.sh
/bin/ls >output1
/bin/cat /etc/redhat-release >output2
```

As you can see, each command in the file now has its stdout sent to a numbered file.  If you want to capture stderr as well, that is just a small change.

Now, run `foo.sh`:

```
$ bash foo.sh
$ cat output1
foo.sh
foo.txt
output1
```

Comment: `With your command as shown, neither ls not cat is actually executed` +1 for that! I really wondered after reading the question again...

Comment: @satish Yes. The point, however, is that the shell does __not__ do word splitting on `$qw`: it takes the whole line, not just the first word, as the name of the command.

Comment: I got it what you saying, what is the work around? i have many command and i want to capture their output in individual file.

Comment: @Satish For a safe way to save the output of each command into a separate file see the last section of the updated answer, the one entitled "Capturing each command's output to a different file".

Answer (score 1):

It happens obviously because the file `/etc/redhat-release` does not exist.

Btw, if you want to execute commands from a file **use a shellscript!**

```
source foo.sh # will execute the commands in the current shell
bash foo.sh   # will launch a new shell to execute the commands
```

The file extension `.sh` is not necessary to make it work. but it should being used by convention.

Comment: For cutting to the heart of the matter and suggesting that the OP use a script: +1.

Comment: file is there `/etc/redhat-release` see my question, which i updated

Comment: I want to capture output of command and store in relevant file

Comment: Have you tried to `source` or execute it as shell script as I've suggested? Probably there are invisible problematic characters in there. For example Windows carriage returns.

Comment: I want to capture output of command also like `ifconfig > ifconfig.txt` that is why i need those command in loop.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is the eval command:

```
while read qw; do eval $qw; done < foo.txt
```

The use of eval is strongly frowned upon though, (as it tends to open up lots of security holes).

Another option is to generate a new script file from the original, using sed to attach redirect tags to the end of each line.

Comment: that works!! what are the security issue with `eval`?

Comment: If someone can manipulate the variable qw, they could append `; rm -rf /` to the end of the variable and wipe your system.  They could also potentially do things more nasty than that.    Which brings up another good point -- you're running commands from foo.txt -- how certain are you that no-one has access to this file?

Comment: `"eval" is a common misspelling of "evil".`

Answer (score 0):

You have the commands you want in foo.txt.
How about:

```
chmod +x foo.txt
./foo.txt > my_output
```

When this works fine, consider renaming foo.txt into foo.sh.